# How to sort AGGRID columns Management tab in ASC order

Tags: ag-grid

I am using **Aggrid** where I need to sort the column list only in Ascending order. I am not seeing any documentation related to that. I cannot alter column definition. Is it possible.?

[image: List of Columns]